# i need execute code when user input number in terminal in python3

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, linux, python-3, rfid

I have this python3 code.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import requests

payload = {}
headers = {}

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(14, GPIO.OUT)
string = input()

def buclick(event):

  url = "http://192.168.0.108:3000/api/main/get?client_bar_code=" + string + "&item_bar_code=1234"
  response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload) 
  if response.text == '1': 
    GPIO.output(14, GPIO.HIGH)
  elif response.text == '0':
    GPIO.output(14, GPIO.LOW)
```

This is a special server to open a door if response is equal 1 and vice versa. How make this code run after read from input()?
note : string read from RFID
thanks advance

Comment: I see no executable code.

Comment: Is this code supposed to be running indefinitely?  Should it lock the door after X seconds?

Comment: yep, should not to be running indefinitely but i complete python3 software with GUI Tkinter the issue was i cant running the program after booting or without screen because my program python3 had gui and entry focus to read RFID serialy but there is no method to make raspberry up gui without screen, i had to change python3 code to this in above  and i'am  beginner in python3 .

Comment: You created a function `buclick` but it is never called in this code.  If this is all the code you have, then that is why it doesn't work.  Since you mentioned TKinter, I'm guessing there is more code that is not posted here.